# Difference between viewEnd and textEnd in android:textAlignment

Tags: android

I was going through documentation of `android:textAlignment` and it has 7 options few of those are `viewEnd/viewStart` and `textEnd/textStart`

I could not understand what is difference in `view####` vs `text####` using docs from the POV of use cases.If anyone can clarify that in more detail using some examples or use cases?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Views.TextAlignment.ViewStart/

Answer (score 2):

My observation,

if the `textDirection` or `layoutDirection` is `ltr` then, `viewStart/End` and `textStart/End` behaves the same.

But if you change one of the `textDirection` or `layoutDirection` to `rtl`, and now try the view/text start/end, you will visually see the difference.

[image: one of the combination]

Answer (score 0):

You can read explanation here: [textAlignment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atextAlignment)

And difference in text and view is pretty simple. I'll explain on an example. Here is a 9.png:

[image: 9.png example]

We are interested in right and bottom black rectangles. This rectangles shows where content should be placed (I've marked it with red rectangle for better understanding). In this current case it is a text. But as you can see this rect is not covering the whole image. In uncovered parts text wouldn't be drawn. So view will contain whole image, but text part (or content part better to say) will be lesser.

Comment: I have already read the explanation as I have already mentioned in the question

Comment: How is this an answer to the asked questions? The answer only tells the diff between view and text. Op asked how it works with textAlignment